# Issuer ID for SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, id

Someone created an Provider hosted App. For that he must have generated some IssuerID. What I know is one IssuerID will be used for all Provider Hosted App.
Now I don't/remember know IssuerID.
Shall I run same powershell command to generate new IssuerId or is there any way I can find existing IssuerID.
Will new issuerID impact existing Provider Hosted App.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following command you can retrieve the IssuerID:

```
Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer
```

Reference - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-issuer-id-for-provider-hosted-addin-in-sharepoint-2016